# Django url_pattern for *.mp3

Tags: regex, django

I am trying to serve some audio files as static files and trying to refrain from using `collectstatic`.

What would be the url_pattern for serving files that ending with .mp3 ?

```
url(r"^static/............mp3", views.serve_mp3)
```

I have already implemented a function based view called `serve_mp3`

Comment: You typically do not want to serve files directly through Django like this. It's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This works for finding the match that ends with .mp3 and starts with static.

```
url(r"^static.*\.mp3$", views.serve_mp3)
```